# How to bind on multiple Either<,>?

Tags: c#, functional-programming, language-ext

I have two functions that return `Either<Error,?>`, and the 2nd function depends on the first one.

```cs
Either<Error, bool> either1 = ReturnEither1(...);
Either<Error, int> either2 = either1.Bind(ReturnEither2);
```

Now, I have a 3rd function which depends on both `either1` and `either2` and its *left* type is also `Error`. How can I do something like below?

```cs
Either<Error, MyType> either3 = [either1, either2].BindAll(...);
```

So I want `either3` to bind to the *right* of both `either1` and `either2`.

Comment: How does `Either` look like? Maybe you can use self-referencing generic constraint

Comment: I don't know csharp syntax, but you usually nest bind calls `either1.Bind((x) => either2.Bind((y) => ReturnEither3(x, y))`.

Comment: @bob, in my case it is a combination of `bind` and `map`. Thanks! Would you convert this into an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have some `BindAll` easily because you will lose type safety (`MyType` vs. individual return types). I guess you could build something using `Fold` on the enumeration of functions if you really think you need something that way.

For what you want I prefer LINQ syntax in C#:

```cs
var result = from x1 in ReturnEither1()
             from x2 in ReturnEither2(x1)
             from x3 in ReturnEither3(x1, x2) // you can use any of the previous results
             select x3;
```

This will call `SelectMany` on the monadic type which is `Bind` (see documentation of [LanguageExt](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/wiki/Thinking-Functionally:-What-is-LINQ-really%3F#so-how-does-it-work)). You get a right value if every function returns right -- otherwise, get the first left value (first error).

Result will be of Either type like return value of `ReturnEither3`. All individual functions (`ReturnEither*`) need same left type, but can have different right type.